# Get last record of each record group

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I don't know how to write the SQL syntax of getting the last record (according to recent post and is not replied to).

My table

```
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| notification_id   | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id           | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_msg  | text                  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| notification_date | int(11) unsigned      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| private_message   | tinyint(1) unsigned   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| has_replied       | tinyint(1) unsigned   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| reply_id          | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Basically for each threaded notification, it should get the last record of each notification record and check if `has_replied` is `0`, if it is 0 then it should return it so PHP can read whether there is a notification that hasn't been replied to. So like, it should return like this (pseudo):

```
+--------------+-----+-----+
| username     | 1   | 4   |
| username2    | 0   | 2   |
+--------------+-----+-----+
```

Where the second column represents if the last post has been replied to or not.

My current SQL syntax (works but does not get the last record and if it's replied to):

```
SELECT n.*,
       m.user_id,
       m.username
FROM notifications n
INNER JOIN members m ON n.user_id = m.user_id
WHERE private_message = 1
AND reply_id = 0
ORDER BY has_replied ASC,
         notification_date DESC
```

Comment: +1. I like the table format `:)`

Comment: what is the third column in the pseudo output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select m.user_id, m.username
    , N...
From members As M
    Join    (
            Select user_id, Max( notification_id ) As notification_id
            From notifications 
            Group By user_id
            ) As UserLastNotification
        On UserLastNotification.user_id = m.user_id
    Join notifications As N
        On N.notification_id = UserLastNotification.notification_id
Where N.private_message = 1
    And N.reply_id = 0
Order By N.has_replied, N.notification_date Desc
```

Note that this will filter on each user's last notification being a private message and having a reply_id being zero.

Comment: Suppose you think `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` would be better than `JOIN`? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @lolwut - `Join` is shorthand for `Inner Join`. Similarly, `Left Join` is shorthand for `Left Outer Join`. However, whether to use a Left Join vs an Inner Join depends on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. If you wanted all members whether they have a notification, then I'd need to move the criteria in the Where clause into the On clause for UserLastNotification.

Comment: Sorry to bother you. But could there be a slight alteration to the SQL syntax to return the `user_level` of the last post each threaded notification. Only if it's not too much hassle. The `user_level` comes from the members table.

Comment: @lolwut - Is there a reason you cannot simply add it to your Select clause since it comes from the members table?

Answer (score 0):

A simple

```
LIMIT 1
```

at the end of the query should be sufficient to only return the last post.